# Is it possible to create a button or a link to call notion api inside notion?

Tags: notion-api

When you open a page from a database in notion, the properties are listed at the top of the page.

I want to be able to modify those properties from inside the page.

For example, the template of the page could be a set of questions to answer by yes or no and when answering a question the corresponding property (checkbox) would be set to yes or no.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

No, Notion does not allow you to execute scripts within the application.